# Permit autentification admin on Exchange

Tags: windows, exchange-server

I want to disable external access to ECP Exchange 2016. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will read main step for solution.

> 1. Run the Add Roles and Features Wizard from the Exchange Server. Select your Exchange Server and follow the wizard. Now you are on the **Server Roles** tab. Expand **Web Server (IIS)** -> **Web Server** -> **Security**. Check the **IP and Domain Restrictions** role. On our end, it’s already installed on the Exchange Server.
>
>    Click on Next. Click **Install** to install the IP and Domain Restrictions role. Installation completes. Proceed further with the steps below.
> 2. Open IIS Manager on the Exchange Server. Expand Server -> **Sites** -> **Default Web Site**. Select **ecp**. Double click on IP Address and Domain Restrictions.
>
>    The IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature is open. Let’s configure it to disable external access to ECP on the Exchange Server 2016. First, click on **Edit Feature Settings**… and configure it to **Deny** access for unspecified clients. Set the Deny Action Type to **Not Found**.
> 3. Click on **Add Allow Entry**… and configure that you can access ECP internal on the Exchange Server (localhost). Add the **IP 127.0.0.0** with **prefix 8**. If you want to add the **subnet mask** instead of the prefix, it should be **255.0.0.0**.
>
>    You added the entry. Now you can log in ECP from the Exchange Server, go to `https://localhost/ecp`. I don’t recommend to open ECP on the whole internal LAN. If you have management servers, add the IP addresses to the allow list.
>
>    You added the entries and it is showing correctly. Start ECP and login from the IP addresses that you added. Make sure you insert the Exchange Server hostname. For example, `https://EX01/ecp`.

**Source:** https://www.alitajran.com/disable-external-access-to-ecp-exchange-2016